# how to properly read a csv file with not standard encoding in d3.js

Tags: csv, d3.js, encoding

I have a small.csv file like this:

```
Game,Country,Number of Users,Average Rating
Formula D,Venezuela,1,9
Formula D√©,Australia,16,7.09
Ticket to Ride: M√§rklin,Argentina,1,9.2
Zooloretto,Vietnam,1,7.2
```

I try to read the file in the standard D3.js way:

```
d3.csv('small.csv').then(data => console.log(data));
```

The problem is the names of the second and third game does not read properly encoded.

The names of the games should be:
Formula Dé instead of Formula D√©
Ticket to Ride: Märklin instead of Ticket to Ride: M√§rklin

How read this file properly?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/paszo/8b3397e90b5d5e8f2c7d1fd05a7cafd4/raw/cc0438d1c70cf786a66551523ab3adadc1c4db2e/small.csv

Comment: The array of objects is Ok, but the names of the games inside the objects are not correct.

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version of d3 (v7.1.1) there doesn't seem to be any problem. Snippet below:

```js
d3.csv(
  'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/shreshthmohan/5af5d1f0a62858bc2cd380838dc00db6/raw/e394fbc220f34f8c8b3adde0ec8e2c8cd2b71726/small.csv',
).then(data => {


  d3.select('body')
    .selectAll('p')
    .data(data)
    .join('p')
    .text(d => d.Game)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.1.1/d3.min.js" integrity="sha512-COTaPOlz12cG4fSfcBsxZsjauBAyldqp+8FQUM/dZHm+ts/jR4AFoJhCqxy8K10Jrf3pojfsbq7fAPTb1XaVkg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: What I expect is that the second row is Formula Dé and the third row is Ticket to Ride: Märklin

Comment: @paszo you need to fix the source csv or use a tool like d3's [dsv2dsv](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv#dsv2dsv) to tackle this. Look at the `--input-encoding` option to convert files from one encoding to another. What's is the source of your csv file and do you know what encoding type is? d3 assumes encoding is `utf-8` by default.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot modify the source file outside of my script. Can you suggest a similar solution to use inside of the code?

Comment: Running this snippet shows the desired output ... ?

Comment: @paszo you can download the file, use the [dsv2dsv](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv#dsv2dsv) utility to convert the encoding and then import it into d3